# Родительный или винительный падеж в сущ "врача"

Tags: падежи

В предложении "Я очень боюсь зубного врача" у сущ. "врача" падеж винительный или родительный?
Ведь можно сказать "боюсь собаку" и "боюсь собаки"
Если можно, ответ с обоснованием.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: *Я очень боюсь зубного **врача** (Р. п.). Я боюсь **собаки** (Р. п.).*

Допускается (разг.): *Я боюсь **собаку** (В. п.)*

**Пояснение**

1. Большой толковый словарь

**БОЯТЬСЯ,** боюсь, боишься; нсв. 1. **кого-чего.** Испытывать боязнь (о человеке или животном). Б. хулиганов, учителя, отца. Б. грозы, землетрясения. Мышей и собак смертельно боюсь. Б. как огня, как чёрт ладана (очень сильно). * Волков бояться - в лес не ходить (Посл.). Режь меня, жги меня: Я тверда, не боюсь Ни ножа, ни огня! (Пушкин).

2. **Управление в русском языке**

**БОЯТЬСЯ** кого-чего / **(разг.) кого (вин. п.).** Мне было ясно, что все боятся матери (М. Г.); Бояться безработицы; Дядю все боялись (Леск.).

Comment: А почему "я очень боюсь лису"?

Comment: Я очень боюсь лису (разг. В.п.) А чем  лиса от собаки отличается? Они очень похожи. я видела в парке лису,  Я лису боюсь, а она меня нет.  Я ей сказала: Пошла вон!   Она посмотрела на меня, что-то подумала и ушла.  Неадекватная лиса.

Comment: №296402
как правильно написать: испугались лисы или испугались лису, т.е. какой падеж должен быть у существительного.

ОТВЕТ
Глагол испугаться требует формы родительного падежа. Верно: испугались лисы.

Comment: А это целая монография про лису  (как ее надо бояться).  https://dikijmir.ru/kak-upotrebit-boitsja-lisy-ili-boitsja-lisu/  Если конкретная лиса, то я боюсь лису. А если вообще: я боюсь лис.